Pyttsxy not playing audio when converted to executable
I have built a chatbot that allows users to replay the latest message. The replay function is connected to the tkinter GUI, and uses pyttsx3 to "speak" an output when a replay button is pressed.
def speak(message):
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    voices = engine.getProperty('voices')  # Get available voices
    engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)  # Set the voice
    engine.setProperty('rate', 200)
    engine.say(message)
    engine.runAndWait()
    return "Your message was spoken!"

Here is the linking:
play_button = Button(bottom_label, text="Replay", font=FONT_BOLD, width=20, bg=BG_VIOLET,
                             command=lambda: speak(last_message))

play_button.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.008, relheight=0.06, relwidth=0.22)

The replay button and speak function works perfectly fine in the IDE when i click run. However, When I created the executable, and tried to replay a message, there was no audio output. It is definitely not an issue with the audio settings, but an issue with the code / executable. How do I fix it?

no error message?

I install pyttsx3 and pyinstaller, and build the following demo code to exe with this command pyinstaller main.py. There is an audio output.
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("I will speak this text")
engine.runAndWait()

Here is the package version:

pyttsx3==2.90
pyinstaller==6.9.0

See if you could solve the issue by updating the packages. If the version is already the same, you can upload a simple demo and I will build it to exe.
